# $V(X|Y)=\Sigma_{XX}-\Sigma_{XY}\Sigma_{YY}^{-1}\Sigma_{YX}$

Tags: variance, conditional-probability, covariance

We know that the conditional variance of a multivariate normal vector $(X,Y)$ is equal to the Schur complement:
$$V(X|Y)=\Sigma_{XX}-\Sigma_{XY}\Sigma_{YY}^{-1}\Sigma_{YX}$$

However, $\Sigma_{XX}-\Sigma_{XY}\Sigma_{YY}^{-1}\Sigma_{YX}$ is a matrix of scalars, whereas $V(X|Y)$ is a matrix of random variables function of Y. Therefore, I guess that the Schur complement is the variance of X conditional to a certain realization of Y, $V(X|Y=(y_1,...,y_n))$, is it correct? If so, who is this $(y_1,...,y_n)$?

Comment: In case of the multivariate normal, the conditional variance happen to not depend on the value of $Y$ you condition on.

Comment: Cross posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3072212/vxy-sigma-xx-sigma-xy-sigma-yy-1-sigma-yx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you say is *in general* true, as @Jarle pointed out, the conditional variance doesn't depend on a specific value in MV gauss case. Please review [this](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Multivariate_normal_distribution#/Conditional_distributions) section, especially the second paragraph, starting with words "*Note that knowing*". Also, a similar [discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/385823/variance-of-conditional-multivariate-gaussian/385844#385844) follows in this topic.

Comment: Thank you very much gunes and Jarle Tufto for this clarification.